# Start intellij from anywhere

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, paths, intellij

I have recently installed Ubuntu and I'm a bit confused.
I have downloaded VSCode and I can simply start it from my terminal using `code`.
I downloaded intellij and tried `idea` and `intellij` but none of them worked.
My Question is:
How can I start Intellij from anywhere in my terminal?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install Intellij?

Comment: Does [this link](https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2017/02/27/start-intellij-idea-command-line/) get you sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the latest IntelliJ IDE on the ubuntu machine
2. navigate to /bin, here you will find a file named something like "intellij-idea-community", run this file and intelliJ will start.
   hope this helps.